# C++: Accessing an unnamed struct member from a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a struct defined outside of a class:

```
struct Boo : public otherClass {
public:
  const float theDataINeed;
}

class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass();
  MyClass(const Boo& Setup);

protected:
  void Method();
}
```

So this is kind of a weird setup because as far as I can tell, the struct instance that's paired with MyClass via the second constructor isn't actually named in a permanent way.

I'm trying to access theDataINeed from within Method(), which I'm trying to write.  Obviously, Setup isn't a permanent name, so I'm stumped as to the exact syntax I need to use here.

```
void MyClass::Method() {
  std::cout<< theDataINeed // Doesn't work
  std::cout<< Setup.theDataINeed // Setup isn't any sort of permanent name, so this doesn't work
}
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
myClass::myClass(const Boo& Setup) 
  : otherClass(Setup) {
}
```

Comment: You can make `theDataINeed` a static data member then write `Boo::theDataINeed`.

Comment: The constructor of `myClass` declares that `Setup` is used for initialization of `otherClass` , while `otherClass` is base class for `Boo` but not for `MyClass`... Please provide a [mre]. We cannot help is we have to guess what the actual code is!

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to create a `static` data member for class `Boo` that will keep track of the value of `Setup.theDataINeed` by assigning it to the static data member so that you can use it inside `MyClass::Method()` as shown below.

```
struct otherClass{};
struct Boo : public otherClass {
public:
  const float theDataINeed;
  
  //static data member to keep track
  static float ms_theDataINeed;
};
//initialize
float Boo::ms_theDataINeed = 0;
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass();
  MyClass(const Boo& Setup)
  {
       //assign Setup to the static data member so that you can use it in Method()
       Boo::ms_theDataINeed = Setup.theDataINeed;

       //other code here
  }
  private:

protected:
  void Method();
};

void MyClass::Method() {
  std::cout<< Boo::ms_theDataINeed; // works now
 
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gdxzv1EnE)

Or instead of having a static data member of type `float` you can have a static data member of type `Boo` and then assign to it the `Setup` in the ctor `MyClass::MyClass(const Boo&)`.